# Checking if employee name is in list before foreach loop

Tags: c#

so I'm trying to check to see whether or not the inputted employee name is equal to an employee name in a list. Can't for the life of me figure out how to achieve this.

Program.cs

```
private static void ReportPersonalUsage()
    {
        string employeename = ReadString("Employee Name:");
        Manager_UI.ReportPersonalUsage(employeename);
    }
```

Manager_UI.cs

```
public static void ReportPersonalUsage(string employeename)
    {
        List<Transaction> Transactions = StockManager.GetAllTransactions();

        Console.WriteLine("\nPersonal Usage Log:");
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0, -19} {1, -6} {2, -3} {3, -10} {4, -10}",
            "Date Taken",
            "Type",
            "ID",
            "Name",
            "Employee");

        foreach (Transaction transaction in Transactions)
        {
            if (transaction.GetEmployee() == employeename)
            {
                DisplayTransaction(transaction);
            }
        }
    }
```

Transaction.cs

```
class Transaction
{
    //Transaction Get/Set
    private Item Item { get; }
    private string Employee { get; }
    private string Type { get; }
    private DateTime Date { get; }
    private double Price { get; }

    //Transaction
    public Transaction(Item item, string type, string employee, DateTime date, double itemprice)
    {
        this.Item = item;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Employee = employee;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Price = itemprice;
    }

    //Get item
    public Item GetItem()
    {
        return this.Item;
    }

    //Get employee
    public string GetEmployee()
    {
        return this.Employee;
    }

    //Get transaction type
    public new string GetType()
    {
        return this.Type;
    }

    //Get transaction price
    public double GetPrice()
    {
        return this.Price;
    }

    //Get transaction date
    public DateTime GetDate()
    {
        return this.Date;
    }
}
```

Not to sure about how to do it though, still fresh to all of this, thanks to anyone that can lend a hand.

Comment: Seeing your, code looks like you come from `Java` background :) Just saying. By the way what's not working in your code?

Comment: you can test if employee exist in list without loop, like : ``bool isEmployeeExist = Transactions.Any(t=>t.GetEmployee() == employeename);``

Comment: @Mathews I do! Good eye, and it's not that something isn't working it's more like I want to implement a feature but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it

Comment: @Sajid would that look something like [this?](https://pasteboard.co/J3nhYjn.png)

Comment: You should know, though, that something like `.Any(...)` *does* have a loop underneath it, even though you don't write one. This can be important if you're searching a large list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ReportPersonalUsage(string employeename)
{
    List<Transaction> Transactions = StockManager.GetAllTransactions();
    bool isEmployeeExist = Transactions.Any(t => t.GetEmployee() == employeename);
    if (isEmployeeExist == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(employeename + " Has Not Taken An Item From Stock Yet, Please Try Again");
    }
    else if (isEmployeeExist == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPersonal Usage Log:");
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0, -19} {1, -6} {2, -3} {3, -10} {4, -10}",
            "Date Taken",
            "Type",
            "ID",
            "Name",
            "Employee");

        foreach (Transaction transaction in Transactions)
        {
            DisplayTransaction(transaction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can replace your ``if..else`` by``if(!isEmployeeExist){}else{}``

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Transaction
{
    //Transaction Get/Set
    public Item Item { get; private set; }
    public string Employee { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public double Price { get; private set; }

    //Transaction
    public Transaction(Item item, string type, string employee, DateTime date, double itemprice)    
    {
       Item = item;
       Type = type;
       Employee = employee;
       Date = date;
       Price = itemprice;
    }
}

public static void ReportPersonalUsage(string employeeName)
{
    IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions = StockManager.GetAllTransactions();

    DisplayHeader();

    foreach(Transaction transaction in transactions)
    {
        if (transaction.Employee == employeeName)
        {
            DisplayTransaction(transaction);
        }
    }
}

private static void DisplayHeader()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nPersonal Usage Log:");
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0, -19} {1, -6} {2, -3} {3, -10} {4, -10}",
        "Date Taken",
        "Type",
        "ID",
        "Name",
        "Employee");
}


private static void DisplayTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{      
    //add the display logic
}
```

- You should work with IEnumerable to take advantage of lazy loading. 
  Only iterate the collection at the point where you need the data.
- Use properties instead of methods in the Transaction POCO.
- Make the private properties to public and make the set private like `public double Price { get; private set;}`